# Sprockets: Compile standalone javascript/stylesheet file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, compilation, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

I added:

```
//= link_directory ../custom/javascripts .js
```

- assets

  - custom

    - javascripts

      - application.js

to `app/assets/config/manifest.js` and assumed that by that I would be able to separately reference the assets living in the `custom` folder from my view:

```
= javascript_include_tag "custom/javascripts/application", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

But I get this error:

> The asset "custom/javascripts/application" is not present in the asset pipeline.

How can I compile `custom/javascripts/application.js` separately from the default `javascripts/application.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest you a different approach. 
Instead adding a folder to manifest.js, why not to add a new custom_application.js in app/assets/javascripts, create a folder app/assets/javascripts/custom and add require for this folder in custom_application.js?

in your app/assets/javascripts/custom_application.js (and everything you need to require)

```
//= require_tree ./custom
```

in your front end app/views/layouts/application.html.erb head include this file

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'custom_application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

and in your config/initializers/assets.rb add this line:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom_application.js )
```

**EDIT:**
If you need another folder instead of default ones, you can add it in app/assets, then edit your app/assets/config/manifest.js:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//#= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../custom .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

in your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb you don't need to specify your path

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

But if you need both application.js from javascripts and custom folders I think you need to rename you custom/application.js

Comment: Or if you don't need older application.js you can add to it //= require_tree ./custom

Comment: Am I able to re-locate `/custom_application.js` to `/gem_name/custom_application.js` and `/custom` to `/gem_name/custom`?

Comment: if gem_name is a folder name, yes, you need to change into gem_name/custom_application javascript_include_tag and %w( gem_name/custom_application.js ) your assets.rb, but you can do it

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks in advance for your guidance!